# You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are configured to process this file. mocha enzyme + webpack

Tags: javascript, mocha.js, enzyme

I am setting up mocha + chai + enzyme to test my react components.
I have set up the webpack.config.js file as below

> webpack.config.js

```
const path = require("path");
const HtmlPlugin = require("html-webpack-plugin");

module.exports = {
    node: {
        fs: 'empty'
    },
    entry: "./App.js",
    output: {
        path: path.join(
            __dirname, '/prod'
        ),
        filename: "app.bundle.js",
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.js$|jsx/,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                use: {
                    loader: 'babel-loader',
                }
            },
            { test: /\.js$|jsx/, use: 'mocha-loader' },
        ],
        options: {
            presets: ["es2015"]
        },
    },
    resolve: {
        extensions: ['*', '.js', '.jsx'],
    },
    plugins: [
        new HtmlPlugin({
            template: './public/index.html'
        })
    ]
}
```

> webpack.config.test.js

const webPackExternals = require('webpack-node-externals')

```
module.exports = {
    mode:'development',
    target: 'node',
    externals: [webPackExternals()],
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\*.test\.js$/,
                use: ['mocha-loader'],
                exclude: /node_modules/,
            },
            { test: /\.css$/, use: 'css-loader' },
        ]
    },
}
```

> package.json

```
{
  "name": "tobacco-free",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "App.js",
  "scripts": {
    "build": "webpack --mode production",
    "dev": "webpack-dev-server --mode development --open --hot",
    "start": "serve ./prod",
    "test": "mocha-webpack --webpack-config webpack.config.test.js \"./src/**/*.test.js\"",
    "coverage": "nyc --reporter=lcov --reporter=text npm run test"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "istanbul-instrumenter-loader": "^3.0.1",
    "mapbox-gl": "^1.8.1",
    "nyc": "^15.0.0",
    "react": "^16.13.0",
    "react-dom": "^16.13.0",
    "react-redux": "^7.2.0",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.1.2",
    "redux": "^4.0.5",
    "redux-thunk": "^2.3.0",
    "serve": "^11.3.0",
    "webpack": "^4.42.0",
    "webpack-cli": "^3.3.11"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-core": "^6.26.3",
    "babel-loader": "7",
    "babel-preset-env": "^1.7.0",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.24.1",
    "chai": "^4.2.0",
    "enzyme": "^3.11.0",
    "enzyme-adapter-react-16": "^1.15.2",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^3.2.0",
    "mocha": "^7.1.1",
    "mocha-loader": "^4.0.2",
    "mocha-webpack": "2.0.0-beta.0",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^3.10.3",
    "webpack-node-externals": "^1.7.2"
  }
}
```

**When I run yarn test, I get this error**
https://github.com/amkayondo/imgBank/blob/master/Annotation%202020-03-21%20173230.jpg

```
You may need an appropriate loader to hand
le this file type, currently no loaders are 
configured to process this file.
```

But I don't know the loader it needs because I added the **use: ['mocha-loader']** In thewebpack.config.js. Please help me with this bug

Comment: Sure, how is mocha going to understand .jsx files on its own? It's not Javascript, you'll _also_ need the babel loader there.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans How do I apply

Comment: What do you mean? You literally already using the babel-loader for js/jsx in your non-test bundle task. As for more details on using loaders, https://webpack.js.org/concepts/loaders/ is the authoritative source, with https://webpack.js.org/configuration/module/#ruleuse explaining multiple loaders for one file type.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans Thank you I fixed the bug using your concept

Comment: probably worth deleting this question again - multiple loaders is a pretty common thing, and has a fair number of tutorials and SO question/answers already.

Comment: cool but I am going to leave for future referencing  

Answer (score 0):

I replaced the `mocha-loader` with `babel-loader` to enable mocha to understand the .jsx files
I also replace the `test: /\*.test.js$\/` with  test: `/\.js$|jsx/` to enable mocha to get access to the **test** and its **component** 
I also add the resolve key to `resolve: { extensions: ['*', '.js', '.jsx'],}` in the **webpack.config.test.js** file to enable mocha to read js and jsx files

> modified webpack.config.test.js

```
const webPackExternals = require('webpack-node-externals')

module.exports = {
    mode:'development',
    target: 'node',
    externals: [webPackExternals()],
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.js$|jsx/,
                use: 'babel-loader',
                exclude: /node_modules/,
            },
            { test: /\.css$/, use: 'css-loader' },
        ]
    },
    resolve: {
        extensions: ['*', '.js', '.jsx'],
    },
}
```